# How to Import Function from different directory in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

I have following file structure:

```
/usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/toolkits/Gecko/script.py
```

In this file ***def getExtents*** is function that I have to access in following file i.e: 
`/usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/default.py`

so I am trying to import function from script.py to the following file:

```
/usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/default.py
```

following line is added in `/usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/default.py`:

```
from orca.scripts.toolkits.Gecko.script import getExtents
```

But I get following errors:

```
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/orca.py", line 1498, in main
    init(pyatspi.Registry)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/orca.py", line 1215, in init
    loadUserSettings()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/orca.py", line 837, in loadUserSettings
    _scriptManager.activate()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/script_manager.py", line 80, in activate
    self.setActiveScript(self.getScript(None), "activate")
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/script_manager.py", line 247, in getScript
    appScript = self.getDefaultScript()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/script_manager.py", line 214, in getDefaultScript
    import scripts.default as default
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/default.py", line 57, in <module>
    from orca.scripts.toolkits.Gecko.script import getExtents
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/toolkits/Gecko/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from script import Script
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/toolkits/Gecko/script.py", line 52, in <module>
    import orca.scripts.default as default
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'default'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need

```
from orca.scripts import default
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, check you've got the relevant `__init__.py`

**edit**: re-reading the stacktrace, looks like you've got a circular import too, you're trying to import orca.scripts.default in line 52 of "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/toolkits/Gecko/script.py"

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for your quick reply But I did this in import line - - - >        from orca.scripts.toolkits.Gecko.script import getExtents

Comment: from orca.scripts.toolkits.Gecko.script import getExtents
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/toolkits/Gecko/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from script import Script
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/toolkits/Gecko/script.py", line 52, in <module>
    import orca.scripts.default as default
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'default'

Comment: See my edit, you're trying to import orca.scripts.default in your Gecko/script.py file

Comment: Hi i got your point that in Gecko/script.py there is circular import is happened but , how can I resolve this situation , so in python circular import is not allowed ?

Comment: Well, I guess you could do it, but the import being wrong is what's causing your exception to be thrown, and you'd be better off trying to refactor to avoid it)